# Как в атрибут value передать полную ссылку на видио youtube в форматe <iframe>

Tags: php, html

Когда я пытаюсь передать ссылку в value таким форматом

```
<iframe width="560" height="315" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/u92df1zv4GA" frameborder="0" allow="accelerometer; autoplay; encrypted-media; gyroscope; picture-in-picture" allowfullscreen></iframe>
```

то в инпуте в атрибуте value храниться не вся строка. Как поместить туда всю строку?

```
   <input class="inputs link" type="text" name="link" value="<iframe width=" 560"="" height="315" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/u92df1zv4GA" frameborder="1" allow="accelerometer; autoplay; encrypted-media; gyroscope; picture-in-picture" allowfullscreen="">
```

мои попытки получить внятные value.  Да кошмар, но пока в голову ничего не пришло

```
 <div class="film-video">
                <?php
                echo '<p class="text">Ссылка: </p>';
                echo '<input class="inputs link" type="text" name="link" value="'
            ?><?php echo $row['link'] ?><?php echo'">' ?>
            </div>
```

Если надо дополнительные строки кода напишу.

Comment: $css='<iframe width="560" height="315" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/u92df1zv4GA" frameborder="0" allow="accelerometer; autoplay; encrypted-media; gyroscope; picture-in-picture" allowfullscreen></iframe>';  echo "<input class='inputs link' type='text' name='link' value=".$css.">";

Comment: @Bloom неа, чет не хочет

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15002652/get-value-of-input-field-inside-an-iframe